# Column layout in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to ExtJs. I need to create an entry form in 2 columns using column layout.

My code is as follows:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){                         

                var patientForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
                    renderTo: "patientCreation",
                    frame: true,
                    title: 'Search Criteria',
                    labelAlign: 'left',
                    labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;',
                    labelWidth: 85,
                    width: 900,
                    items: [
                    {
                        layout:'column',
                        items:[
                        {   // column #1
                            columnWidth: .33,
                            layout: 'form',
                            items: [
                                {   xtype: 'textfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'FirstName',
                                    name: 'firstName',
                                    vtype : 'alpha',
                                    allowBlank:false
                                },{
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'MiddleName',
                                    name: 'middleName',
                                    vtype : 'alpha'             
                                }
                            ] // close items for first column
                        }]
                    }]

                        });         
                        var win = new Ext.Window({                          
                            layout:'form',
                            closable: false,
                            resizable: false,
                            plain: true,
                            border: false,
                            items: [patientForm]
                        });
            win.show();
            });
```

But when I run the code, I got *h is undefined error*. How to design a form in column layout? Is there any procedure, steps or links which give a clear idea?

Comment: Are you using ExtJS 3? or ExtJS 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run the same code with ExtJs 3.2.2 and got a similar error. But when I removed `renderTo: "patientCreation"`
code worked:
[image]

That part is not necessary 'cause you are placing the form in a the window.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about ExtJS 3. If you are using ExtJS 4, then you have specified `layout` config at wrong place. You have specified it inside `items` config, it should not be inside `items` config.

Layout can be specified as follows in ExtJS 4:

```
Ext.define('your_domain_name.viewName', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.any_name_you_want',
    layout : 'column',

    initComponent : function() {
        this.items = [
            // all items inside form/panel will go here
        ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

You can get sample code about all the panels [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html)

Answer (score 0):

try applying `renderTo` config to window instead of form

check [example](http://jsfiddle.net/EVr74/)